# How do I display the index of my 2D array when I already bubble sorted it?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

My problem requires me to display the index of my array that I already sorted using bubble sort. But I'm not sure how to do so.

```
int hdb[3][5] = {{5510, 5538, 5519, 5543, 5540},
                 {6627, 7656, 8603, 9201, 9404},
                 {3623, 4388, 4861, 5293, 5817}};
int j, temp;

printf("The number of applications for the 3-room HDB flat is:\n");

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  if (hdb[0][j] > hdb[0][j + 1]) {
    temp = hdb[0][j];
    hdb[0][j] = hdb[0][j + 1];
    hdb[0][j + 1] = temp;
  }
  printf("%d in index %d\n", hdb[0][j], j + 1);
}
```

and it displays:

```
The number of applications for the 3-room HDB flat is:
5510 in index 1
5519 in index 2
5538 in index 3
5540 in index 4
5543 in index 5
```

but my expected output should be:

```
The number of applications for the 3-room HDB flat is:
5510 in index 1
5519 in index 3
5538 in index 2
5540 in index 5
5543 in index 4
```

Comment: But the output you get is the correct output. The output you expect is *before* the (partial!) sorting. After the sorting those indexes are no longer valid.

Comment: is there any way i can get to my expected output? maybe like bubble sorting the indexs(?), sorry im new at coding haha

Comment: While bubble sorting the values always treat a second array (containing the indexes) the same way. Or use structs which contain value and initial index.

Comment: You have arrays of 5 elements. This implies that the index of the last element is 4. You then iterate with j from 0 to 4 and compare element at position j and j+1. But when j=4, it will compare elements at index 4 and 5. There is no element with index 5. You thus overflow your array. Please fix that bug.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to sort the (sub-) arrays? Why do you need to print the old (original) indexes? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), because your question is one.

Comment: You print the array values in the same loop as you bubble sort the array. You should first sort the array and then, in a second loop, print all the array elements. Another problem is that you didn't implement a full bubble sort. You only have one pass over the values. You need more than that. It happens that the initial order of values allows to sort them in a single pass, but this is not always the case.